# Parse File and store into Map function with multiple value in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hashmap

I'm parsing the below file format:

> //URL//
>
> account/42
>
> //Status//
>
> 200
>
> //HEADERS//
>
> content-type=application/json
>
> //BODY//
>
> { "name": "xyz" }
>
> //URL//
>
> account/43

I would like to store multiple value for single key in map function.

**current output**

```
{ url: [ undefined, 'account/42', undefined, 'account/43' ],

 status: [ undefined, '200' ],

 headers: [ undefined, 'content-type=application/json' ],

 body: [ undefined, '{ "name": "xyz" }' ] }
```

**Expected output**

```
{ url: [ 'account/42', 'account/43' ],

 status: [ '200' ],

 headers: [  'content-type=application/json' ],

 body: [  '{ "name": "xyz" }' ] }
```

**below are the code**

```
var fs = require('fs');

function parseFile(){

var content;

fs.readFile("src/main/resources/FileData1.txt", function(err, data) {

    if(err) throw err;

    content = data.toString().split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g).map(function(line){

        return line.trim();

    }).filter(Boolean) 
    console.log(processFile(content));

});

}

function processFile(nodes) {

var map={};

var key;

nodes.forEach(function(node) {

    var value;

    if(node.startsWith("//")){

        key = node.substring(2, node.length-2).toLowerCase();     

    }

    else{

        value = node;

    }

   // map[key] = value;

    if(key in map){

        map[key].push(value);

    }else{

        map[key]= [value]; 
    }
});

return map;    

}
```

Okay , I can see the problem is with declaration of "Value", As I want to store multiple value and I'm not sure when & how to declare the value. Even if I declare the value as globally it will stored the previous value.
Problem: How to store multiple value in map?

Comment: Your expected output for `url` has `{ url: [ 'account/42',, 'account/43' ],` why does it have the empty second value?

Comment: It was mis print, my expected value of url should be like `code` {url : ['account/42', 'account/43']

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is caused by continuing after you have already determined a line is a key. The body continues to execute after this:

```
if(node.startsWith("//")){
    key = node.substring(2, node.length-2).toLowerCase();           
}
```

and eventually hits the part where you assign a value. But value is not defined since this line is a `key`. A simple fix is to return after setting the key:

```
if(node.startsWith("//")){
    key = node.substring(2, node.length-2).toLowerCase();     
    return; // continue to the next line
}
```

Working example:

```js
// data after parsing text
let data = [ '//URL//','account/42','//Status//','200','//HEADERS//','content-type=application/json','//BODY//','{ "name": "xyz" }','//URL//','account/43' ]

function processFile(nodes) {

  var map = {};
  var key;

  nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    var value;
    if (node.startsWith("//")) {
      key = node.substring(2, node.length - 2).toLowerCase();
      return
    } else {
      value = node;
    }

    // map[key] = value;

    if (key in map) {
      map[key].push(value);
    } else {
      map[key] = [value];
    }
  });

  return map;
}
let m = processFile(data)
console.log(m)
```